# How post data in ASP.NET Core (frontend to backend (React))

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

It is my react code to hit the API on submit button
I update the question and add a new class httpresponemessage post

```
const handleOnPreview = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        setsubmittext(text);
        const ROOT_URL='https://localhost:7113/';
        axios.post(`${ROOT_URL}/api/demo-text`, text, {
            headers: { 'Content-type':'application/json'} 
        })
    }
```

This is my controller in ASP.NET Core MVC:

```
public class HomeController: Controller
{
    private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;

    public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

[HttpPost]
    [Route("/api/demo-text")]
    [EnableCors("AllowOrigin")]
    public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromForm] text text)
    {
        return new HttpResponseMessage()
        {
            Content = new StringContent("POST: Test message")
        };
    }
    
    public IActionResult Privacy()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

### Startup.cs
this is the middleware file of my project

### MiddleWare

```
 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
               
                app.UseHsts();
            }
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseCors();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
```

last error I get

[image]

[image]
I want the HTTP post method to post the data.

Comment: What error you are getting?

Comment: I doest know how to create a connection between the front end and backend

Comment: I create a method in react they are working they hit the API route but I don't know how to do it in a post in asp .net core MVC

Comment: Use postman and hit your api from there. If you are able to get response, do same in React.  Take help of Sample Code on SO and Github

Comment: can you provide some links for that

Comment: You can refer to this [issue](https://www.guru99.com/postman-tutorial.html) to use postman test your api.

Comment: when you submit the button, THe project send the request successfully?

Comment: no cors error occure

Comment: yes from react request successfully sent

Comment: @gouravkumar have you enabled cors and made allow any origin or specified url, in your backend?

Comment: What do you mean by "I want the HTTP post method to post the data." ? If request is sent correctly from react, is done!

Comment: @Maruf yes I updated my asp.net controller

Comment: @JRichardsz but it shows error cros error

Comment: Update the question title and body mentioning CORS error. CORS error are very common and easy to fix with just some headers in the response.

Comment: @JRichardsz please fix this issue

Comment: I'd change `[FromForm]` to `[FromBody]`. You're submitting JSON, not a form.

Comment: share your github repository

Comment: And please do not change your question, just add updates, it may reflect the given answers earlier.

Comment: `app.UseCors()` must be defined after `app.UseRouting()`

Answer (score 0):

If you have not yet, you need to define the `cors` policy in your asp.net core.

In `Startup` class:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
  services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy(options.DefaultPolicyName,
                                                        policy => policy.AllowAnyOrigin()
                                                                .AllowAnyHeader()
                                                                .AllowAnyMethod());
            });
}
```

and in your configuration of the HTTP request pipeline method

```
 public async void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
 {
   // ... other middlewares
   app.UseCors(); 
  // ... other middlewares 
 }
```

**Attention:** this allows for any origin and may cause security problems. Just do that for checking and testing. Not suggested in production.

Comment: my project was built in .net 6

Comment: uh, please, do some research on how to write it in .net6.0 :)

Comment: i have 500 http error `System.InvalidOperationException: Endpoint TextUtilites.Controllers.HomeController.Post (TextUtilites) contains CORS metadata, but a middleware was not found that supports CORS.`

Comment: please update your question by posting, how you have configured your request pipeline

Comment: same like you have defined in the answer

Comment: Please add yours, I have defined just general, there should be, other middlewares as well such as, `routing`, `endpoints` etc

Comment: yes i have added that one also

Comment: can you find any solution?

Comment: in order to get solution provide additional info, your middleware configuration and last error you are getting

Comment: wait I update the question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245969/discussion-between-maruf-and-gourav-kumar).